# What should I do since my bent over row form was completely wrong?

Tags: stronglifts, form

So, because I'm a bit silly and I guess I misread the description and never looked at any videos for it, I've been doing bent over rows completely wrong.  Instead of having my back mostly parallel with the ground, i was bending over roughly 45 degrees or so and doing it that way.

My current weight is 115.  Should I drop it 10-20% and start there (90-105)?  Or...?

Comment: Where is your deadlift and press? And chins, if you do them?

Comment: @daveliepmann dl: 195lbs 5x5, bench press: 100lbs 5x5, ohp: 95lbs 5x5.  Dunoo what my 1rm are, those are my current working weights.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to just adjust your form and keep your current weight, but in order to be sure that you don't accidentally jump much closer to your 1RM, I'd drop to 95 pounds and restart the progression on bent-over rows.

Taking twenty pounds off should be plenty to make sure you can do the exercise with corrected form. It's also not a huge drop in weight in absolute terms.

*Disclaimer: I haven't done bent-over rows in years, and only got about as far as you are now. This advice is based on the other pressing and pulling I do, in which I am merely a beginner.*